# Best way to remove multiple entries from kml file

Tags: bash, macos, command-line, kml

I have a very large KML file (over 20000 placemarkers). They are named by numbers which go up in increments of 5 starting at about 7000 up to 27000.

```
<Placemark>
    <name>7750</name>
    <description><![CDATA[converted by:</br><a href="http://gridreferencefinder.com/">GridReferenceFinder.com</a></br>]]></description>
    <Point>
        <coordinates>-0.99153654,52.225002,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
```

I would like to remove any placemarker that doesnt end in 00 or 50. Having a placemarker every 5 metres is slowing down some of the lower end devices on site.

Is there some script, command or whatever that will check the name and if it doesn't end in 00 or 50 delete from `<Placemark>` to `</Placemark>` for that entry?

You would literally be saving me 10 hours work deleting them individually.

Comment: Is your file line from `<Placemark>` to `<Placemark>`  always fix in length? or not? Is that 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **Perl-one liner** solution!

*I would like to remove any placemarker that doesnt end in 00 or 50*
First of all a solution for this; match anything except for ones end with `00` or `50`

```
^(?:[7-9]\d|[1-2]\d\d)(?!00|50)\d\d$
```

Demo:

## [`^(?:[7-9]\d|[1-2]\d\d)(?!00|50)\d\d$`](https://regex101.com/r/dKHG2s/2)

A fest test can be:

```
perl -le 'print for grep{ /^(?:[7-9]\d|[1-2]\d\d)(?=00|50)\d\d$/  } 7000..27000'
```

then read the entire file once:

```
$/=undef;
```

then read all matches with a while loop:

```
while/<Placemark>\s*?<name>(?:[7-9]\d|[1-2]\d\d)(?!00|50)\d\d.*?<\/Placemark>/sg
```

`s` flag is for reading as a single line or `.` can match newline, and `g` for global search

then print the match (`S&`):

```
perl -lne '$/=undef;print $& while/<Placemark>\s*?<name>(?:[7-9]\d|[1-2]\d\d)(?!00|50)\d\d.*?<\/Placemark>/sg' file
```

pattern for match:

```
<Placemark>\s*?<name>(?:[7-9]\d|[1-2]\d\d)(?!00|50)\d\d.*?<\/Placemark>
```

demo:

[`<Placemark>\s*?<name>(?:[7-9]\d|[1-2]\d\d)(?!00|50)\d\d.*?<\/Placemark>`](https://regex101.com/r/ivSHgb/3)

---

NOTE:
If you notice this part `(?!00|50)` it is an exclude matcher that by using a **lookahead**, you can make it opposite, that means:

```
^(?:[7-9]\d|[1-2]\d\d)(?=00|50)\d\d$
```

only matches things that end with `00` or `50`.
So you can use this to switch between what you want and what you do not want.

#### print all patterns that does not end with `00` or `50`

```
perl -lne '$/=undef;print $& while/<Placemark>\s*?<name>(?:[7-9]\d|[1-2]\d\d)(?!00|50)\d\d.*?<\/Placemark>/sg' file
```

#### print all patterns that end with `00` or `50`

```
perl -lne '$/=undef;print $& while/<Placemark>\s*?<name>(?:[7-9]\d|[1-2]\d\d)(?!00|50)\d\d.*?<\/Placemark>/sg' file
```

#### How to Substitute

if you like, you can use operator: `s/regex-match/substitute-string/`

```
perl -pe '$/=undef;s/<Placemark>\s*?<name>(?:[7-9]\d|[1-2]\d\d)(?!00|50)\d\d.*?<\/Placemark>/==>DELETE<==/sg' file
```

test:
input:

```
before...
<Placemark>
    <name>7700</name>
    <description><![CDATA[converted by:</br><a href="http://gridreferencefinder.com/">GridReferenceFinder.com</a></br>]]></description>
    <Point>
        <coordinates>-0.99153654,52.225002,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
after...
---------
before...                                                                                                                                                                                              
<Placemark>                                                                                                                                                                                            
    <name>7701</name>                                                                                                                                                                                  
    <description><![CDATA[converted by:</br><a href="http://gridreferencefinder.com/">GridReferenceFinder.com</a></br>]]></description>                                                                
    <Point>
        <coordinates>-0.99153654,52.225002,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
after...
--------
before...
<Placemark>
    <name>27650</name>
    <description><![CDATA[converted by:</br><a href="http://gridreferencefinder.com/">GridReferenceFinder.com</a></br>]]></description>
    <Point>
        <coordinates>-0.99153654,52.225002,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
after...
--------
before...
<Placemark>
    <name>27651</name>
    <description><![CDATA[converted by:</br><a href="http://gridreferencefinder.com/">GridReferenceFinder.com</a></br>]]></description>
    <Point>
        <coordinates>-0.99153654,52.225002,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
after...

end.
```

the output:

```
before...
<Placemark>
    <name>7700</name>
    <description><![CDATA[converted by:</br><a href="http://gridreferencefinder.com/">GridReferenceFinder.com</a></br>]]></description>
    <Point>
        <coordinates>-0.99153654,52.225002,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
after...
---------
before...                                                                                                                                                                                              
==>DELETE<==
after...
--------
before...
<Placemark>
    <name>27650</name>
    <description><![CDATA[converted by:</br><a href="http://gridreferencefinder.com/">GridReferenceFinder.com</a></br>]]></description>
    <Point>
        <coordinates>-0.99153654,52.225002,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
after...
--------
before...
==>DELETE<==
after...

end.
```

NOTE.2:

you can use `-i` for edit-in-place

```
perl -i.bak -pe ' ... the rest of the script ...' file
```

It is better to use perl `5.22` or upper version

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in awk:

```
$ awk '
/<Placemark>/ { d=""; b="" }         # d is delete, b is buffer, reset both
{ b=b $0 (/<\/Placemark>/?"":ORS) }  # gather data to d
!/[50]0</ && /<\/name>/ { d=1 }      # if not 50 or 00 set del flag
/<\/Placemark>/ && d!=1 { print b }  # print b if not marked delete
' file
```

It only works with well formed input, especially:

```
...
</Placemark>
<Placemark>
...
<name>1234</name>
...
```

not:

```
...
</Placemark><Placemark>
... <!-- or: -->
<name>1234
</name>
...
```

It's an ugly hack. Someone will probably set you up with something nicer but try it if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$0 == "<Placemark>" {cnt=cnt+1} {arry[cnt]=arry[cnt]$0"\n";if ($0 ~ /<name>/) {match($0,/[[:digit:]]+/);num=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);numbs[num]=cnt}} END { for ( i in numbs ) {if ( substr(i,length(i)-1,length(i)) == "00" || substr(i,length(i)-1,length(i)) == "50") { print arry[numbs[i]] } } }' filename
```

An alternate awk solution is as above. We first set a counter for an array when $0 = . Then we set the array arry for each Placement element in the file. As we do this we also check for the the name index in the file. When we find this, we pattern match the number within (match function) and then use this to sets another array numbs that tracks the numbers against the counter for each placement element. We finally loop through each elements in numbs, checking the number to ensure it ends in 50 or 00. If it does, the arry index is printed.